# Insert data from .sql file in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm creating a wordpress plugin that need to create a table and insert location data to that. There are more than 50000 locations in that INSERT query, so that in separate `.sql` file.

I need to run that when I active the plugin. I'm creating table like below

```
function locations_install()
{
    global $wpdb;
    global $locations_db_version;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'setfordslocations';

    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name (
            id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            town varchar(2000) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
            county varchar(225) NOT NULL,
            country varchar(225) NOT NULL,
            latitude decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
            longitude decimal(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
            postcode varchar(10) NOT NULL,
            type varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY  (id)
        ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);

    add_option('locations_db_version', $locations_db_version);
}
```

How should I run the `.sql` file and insert data?

Comment: You're trying to insert 50,000 rows automatically for a plugin?

Comment: yes. this is custom plugin that need those locations data

Comment: This is a question for [wordpress.se].

Answer (score 0):

A simple and efficient way of doing it:

```
exec('mysql -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD database_name < /path/to/file.sql')
```

If that's not an option, you can open the file and execute the inserts line by line iterating over the file until you reach EOF.